# Can't find the FirebaseStorage module and have already imported it via CocoaPods, has it been changed? - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, storage, firebase-storage

So I want to work with FirebaseStorage and have already imported the CocoaPod required and installed it but when I go to import the module, the FirebaseStorage module is not there. Has it been changed of name, or am I doing something wrong?
Best Regards

[Here's the screenshot of my CocoaPods file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J62Be.png)
 and [the screenshot from my Xcode File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJQl3.jpg)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Can you show how you added FirebaseStorage into your Pod file?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo! Just added both screenshots to my post, the Pod file & the Xcode Proyect!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding you dependencies with `cmd + b`? Sometimes it happens that Xcode is kind of buggy

Comment: I hadn't! Just appeared! Thank you Rodrigo!

Comment: Sure! no problem. I'll add an answer for future references to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes after installing/updating your Podfile, Xcode fails to recognize dependencies, you can force it to identify them by rebuilding the project. You can do it in two ways:

1. Anywhere in your Xcode workspace pressing `cmd + b`
2. In Xcode menu Product > Build

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be due to the most recent CocoaPods update for Firebase 5.0 (see: Version 5.0.0 in [Firebase iOS Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) for more about why they changed it).
So, just make sure you have `pod 'Firebase/Core'` included.

I encountered a similar issue earlier when I ran `pod update` for firebase, in that I had to change my imports around in each file for my build to not fail.  The Import before was

```
import Firebase
```

However Now I have to use

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
```

In order to access firebase storage via `Storage.storage().reference().child()`. Hope that helps, it does sound similar to my issue. Assuming that the CocoaPods and everything are installed properly for your `.xcworkspace`.

Comment: Thanks KSigWyatt. I already tried what you suggested. I did the import Firebase first, but the FirebaseStorage is still no where to be found. I'll edit my question to put my screenshots so that you can see them.

Comment: Then you probably just need to clean & rebuild, `cmd + shift + K` `cmd + B`

Answer (score -1):

"import FirebaseStorage"
it worked for me